# node crashing with http://www.nearby.org.uk/api/

Tags: node.js

os2stl error when submitting postcode, how do i check what im getting back to start with?

getting error http://i.imgur.com/oGx4kOL

code at http://pastebin.com/jvFiH8sP

the https proxy thing is just this

```
http.request = function (options, callback) {
var __options = options;
__options.path = 'http://' + options.host + options.path;
__options.host = proxy.host;
__options.port = proxy.port;
if (_debug) {
    console.log('=== http-proxy.js begin debug ===');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(__options, null, 2));
    console.log('=== http-proxy.js end debug ===');
}
var req = __request(__options, function (res) {
    callback(res);
});
return req;
};

module.exports = function (host, port, debug) {
    proxy.host = host;
    proxy.port = port;
    _debug = debug || false;
};
```

Comment: The linked code does not appear to include the provided code. Where is `__request` defined? It is unlikely you want to `return req;` before `callback(res);` which is what is happening presently due to `__request` likely being asynchronous.

Comment: ok, thanks, ive rewritten it with some different code ( pastebin.com/LMJML9GY ) following advice as far as http proxies are concerned (bodging this somewhat ( stackoverflow.com/questions/3862813/how-can-i-use-an-http-proxy-with-node-js-htt‌​p-client ) , tripping on a different error now... pastebin.com/KwUdNquy